# How do you pass a parameter to defineMessages in react-intl?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-intl

I have an error message like the one below:

`Could not retrieve data: ${e}`

How do I convert this to a definedMessage that can accept this error parameter?

A standard definedMessage:

```
    const messages = defineMessages({
     dataError: {
         id: 'data.error',
         defaultMessage: 'Could not retrieve data: [default message]'
     }
   })
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If I understood you correctly like this:

```
const messages = defineMessages({
  dataError: {
    id: 'data.error',
    defaultMessage: 'Could not retrieve data: {message}'
  }
})

<FormattedMessage
  {...messages.dataError}
  values={{message: `Could not retrieve data: ${e}`}}
/>
```

Answer (score 10):

need to replace `[default message]` with `{e}` in `defineMessages`

```
const messages = defineMessages({
  dataError: {
    id: 'data.error',
    defaultMessage: 'Could not retrieve data: {e}'
  }
})
```

**Define Message variable**

```
 const message = "Error Message";
```

**Pass message variable in Formatted Message**

```
 <FormattedMessage
          {...messages.dataError}
          values={{ e: `${message}` }}
 />
```

**Out Put in below**

```
<span>Could not retrieve data: Error Message</span>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: @reectrix,  If my answer seems helpful to you, vote, please.

Comment: Hello, what if I want

const messages = defineMessages({
  dataError: {
    id: 'data.error',
    defaultMessage: (e,t) => {
       return {
           id: e, defaultMessage: t
}
}
  }
})